# Voltage based automatic switching

Tags: mosfet, resistors, diodes

I have a circuit that operates on 5V. To incorporate 12V functionality, I added a DC-to-DC buck converter module(Input 6.5-15V, Output 5V). Currently, I use a switch to select between 5V and 12V, but I'm interested in implementing automatic voltage selection.

If the input is 5V, bypass the DC-DC buck converter. If it's 12V, route it through the DC-DC buck converter before supplying it to the circuit.

What options do I have?

I am attaching a circuit; please share your insights on it.

Is the LM393 comparator the optimal approach, or are there better alternatives?

[image]

([Image also here](https://i.imgur.com/hskC3Qz.png))

Comment: Diagram flow left to right / input to output is conventional.

Comment: Is it an option to power your circuit from 3v3? If so, id select a 4.5-14V->3V3 DC/DC. Simplest solution

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks, I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent No, I need 5V for some sensors too, so I can't go with 3V3

Comment: @Techno97 - Hi, This question is a "delete & repost" of your [previous question](/q/691606). That behaviour is not allowed. Among other problems, it can waste the time of site members who do the same analysis again and the previous comments are effectively lost. || If you are not getting answers to a question, the [help] has advice in [this article](/help/no-one-answers). Note that it does *not* say to delete & repost the question. || Please do *not* repost a question again, after posting it once (with or without doing a deletion of a previous version). Thanks.

Comment: Use a SEPIC DC/DC converter topology. This can cover the whole input voltage range without the need of takeover thresholds.

Comment: So you really need a 5v output regulator that can handle 12v (5v-12v) inputs, at what current?

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for the heads-up; I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @Jens I already bought some LDOs; I will check those next time.

Comment: @Rodo 700-750mA

Answer (score 0):

In your schematic, the gate of the nMOSFET will either be Vin x R2/R1, or 5.1V, whichever is smaller. This doesn't give the behavior you want, and when Vin is large, the nMOSFET gate will be large, pulling down the gate of the pMOSFET, opening it - when I think you need this to work the other way around.

So firstly, use an nMOSFET for both. Secondly, if you use the Zener diode in series, it basically acts as an open circuit untill the voltage accross it exceeds it's breakdown voltage. In this way, we can basically set the a gate voltage to be Vin - 5.1V, or 0V - whichever is greater. Look at the simulation below.[image]

Where the 10 Ohm resistor is standing in for the load. When the voltage is 12V, the right-hand mosfet doesn't open, when it's 5V it will. You can play with this [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKADMKNCRs8AWEIQTdeA7CnDQkMSChYAnQcJ6E8SkZAFUw8FgHd1PTSBwat%20k9hEIJpo%20cV2%204y9z7Fu2yBaFu4h908LJw8A0O8DJxc7USgFQ1wBBC57KGQ4FmwBAC86ADs6eQYEaG4IMGgMMGcbPDBiFDr4FEZyKhRYeC7u-CTS8BZszhF%20YdSJXIKiksJ45JGklMC0nV0DeZBl303wlgA3EDwXZaOJRLSqPm0JKlupC1PUmOMIw%20PQkKCObas1GNUeBIKtJYHIgA).

As long as you're guaranteed to only have 5V, or a voltage high enough for your LDO to correctly operate I think this should work. The final step of connecting the two power routes together with diodes also works. You could improve the efficiency of this step by changing these to Schottky, or further still by using Mosfets. It depends on how much your design cares about the difference between 5V and 4.7V.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check the schematic and provide the solution. I have redone it as per your solution; can you please check if everything is okay?

https://i.imgur.com/1vpEpEG.png

Yes, the voltage is fixed, either 5V or 12V. Yes, I will use a Schottky diode only, and 4.7V will work.

Comment: Look good to me now.

Comment: Not working; tried to simulate it in Proteus.
Please check https://imgur.com/a/sPlHMAt

Comment: You've wired your voltmeter incorrectly. M2 needs to be in parallel with R4, not series.

Comment: Did that too after posting here, but I get a reading in M1 only, no matter if it's 12V or 5V. M2 shows 1.26V

https://imgur.com/a/Ateq0tF

Comment: It looks like you've used a Schottky, not a zener. If that's not it, I suggest you use the simulation in my answer to work it out. Compare voltages at nodes etc.

Comment: No, it's a zener only, 5.6/5.1V. Added a meter at a different point and removed Q2. It worked here, but when the voltage is 5V, it shows on both meters, and when it's 12V, it shows on M1 only. Is this expected behavior? Or should I get 5V on M2 only and not M1?

https://imgur.com/a/iOtLMDf

Comment: Please use the simulation in my answer to aid your understanding